# django-chosen in django admin: new item in inline forms does not work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following example :

models.py

```
class Book (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(u'Book Title', max_length=300)

class AthoursBook(models.Model):
    chapter = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
    booksathours = models.ManyToManyField(Book, through=u'Athour', verbose_name=u'Athours on book')

class Athour(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u'Athour Name', max_length=300)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

admin.py

```
class AthourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookInline]
    extra = 0

class BookInlineForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        widgets = {
                'book': Select(attrs={'class': 'chozen-css'}),
            }

class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    form = BookInlineForm
    extra = 0
```

I want to use django-chosen in django admin 
but it doesn't work on add new button (on the inline form) as shown on the picture... any ideas? Thanks!
I also tried chosen on its own with no luck...

I mean is this possible? - inlines follow my manytomany model which is implemented this way for many other reasons... Django version 1.5.

[image: django-admin screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

this is not a problem with django-chosen.

the problem is that the new row is hidden and empty by default. When you click on the add link, this row is displayed and filled,

so first you need to revert the .chosen() of the empty select, then apply the .chosen method() after the select is filled.

I solved the problem, adding the following javascript in the change_form.html template

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    $("#book_set-group select").chosen();
    // reverting chosen on the SELECT of the empty row
    $("#id_book_set-__prefix__-athour").chosen('destroy');

    $('#book_set-group .add-row').click(function(e){
        $("#book_set-group select").chosen();
        // reverting chosen on the SELECT of the empty row
        $("#id_book_set-__prefix__-athour").chosen('destroy');
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It only works for one new row and I assume is because after that very select converted to chozen-select the event can't create a correct new select row...